# Gridview linkbutton event not fired

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an asp.net application and I have a delete image button like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdPaymethods" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grdPaymethods_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdPaymethods_RowDeleting">
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="IBtnDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="Click to delete"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MethodId") %>'
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return deleteItem(this.name, this.alt);"
                                ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png" AlternateText='<%# Eval("MethodId") %>'
                                CommandName="Delete" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and I see that row deleting event is fired. but I want to use linkbutton instead of image button. So I used this code:

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="IBtnDelete1" runat="server" ToolTip="Click to delete" 
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MethodId") %>'
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return deleteItem(this.name, this.alt);"
                                Text="Delete" AlternateText='<%# Eval("MethodId") %>'
                                CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

It shows link button, but clicking link button just refreshes page and doesnt call row deleting event. I tried OnRowCommand="grdPaymethods_RowCommand" event and linkbutton on click events as well but they are not fired and page just refreshed.

here are js functions:

```
 function deleteItem(uniqueID, itemID) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dialogTitle = 'Permanently Delete Item ' + itemID + '?';

            $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").html('<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Please click delete to confirm deletion.</p>');

            $("#deleteConfirmationDialog").dialog({
                title: dialogTitle,
                buttons: {
                    "Delete": function () {
                        __doPostBack(uniqueID, '');
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                }
            });

            $('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }



  $(function () {
            InitializeDeleteConfirmation();
        });

        function InitializeDeleteConfirmation() {
            $('#deleteConfirmationDialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Delete": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

and row deleting event:

```
protected void grdPaymethods_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            // cancel the automatic delete action
            e.Cancel = true;

            // do the delete
           // _categoryResposite.DeleteCategories(Convert.ToInt32(e.id));


            grdPaymethods.DataSource = customer.PaymentMethods.OrderByDescending(a => a.Preferred);
            grdPaymethods.DataBind();


        }
```

Please suggest solution to it.

Comment: are you using update panel?

Comment: no, I am not using update panel.

Comment: tried debugging? is it calling your deleteItem() or not?

Comment: You might be binding `GridView` on `Page_Load` event.

Comment: deleteitem is called and dialog is shown

Comment: yes i am binding it on page load but image button is working

Comment: Can you show us your grdPaymethods_RowDeleting event ?.

Comment: @gkrishy done, please check

Comment: `AlternateText` is not the property of `LinkButton`. This may not be the cause, but remove it and try.

Comment: @Bharadwaj, i think "Delete": function () {
                        __doPostBack(uniqueID, ''); is causing postback but after post back no event is fired. in case of imagebutton it works

Comment: Ok, then `return true` from `deleteItem`, now it is `false`.